# Is there any way to "group by" by date with Django.models when my MySQL field has hours/min/second as well?

Tags: mysql, django, or-mapper

I want to query to MySQL using Django.models, but since I put my `created_at` (Datetime field) with `datetime.datetime.now()`, it seems to hard to "group by" with each date. I made a query like this:

```
start = time.strptime("2012/6/25","%Y/%m/%d")
end = time.strptime("2012/6/26","%Y/%m/%d")
unix_start= time.mktime(start)
unix_end = time.mktime(end)
```

`Mymodels.objects.filter(created_at__range[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_start),datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_end]).values("~~~~~").annotate(player_id=Coun`t("player_id"))

but I guess this query is too heavy for network.Is there any way to "group by" by datetime.date or use (date() for MySQL)in Django.models when my MySQL data is datetime.datetime.now()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PostgreSQL `date_trunc()` to group values by a date when the dates are saved as Datetime. I think you can use something like this with MySQL:

```
select_date = {"date": """DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d')"""}
query = query.extra(select=select_date).values('date')
query = query.annotate(player_id=Count('player_id', distinct=True)).order_by('date')
```

Comment: thanks!I made it with this : cls.objects.extra(select={'month': 'extract( month from created_at )','day':'extract(day from created_at)'}).values("day","month","~~~","~~~").annotate(id=Count("id"))

Comment: you have to do "from django.db.models import Count" in advance.